# Why page scrolls when showing Jquery-ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Whenever i display a jquery-ui modal dialog scrollbars appear in the page.

this is how i display the dialog

```
$("#Frmula").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 250,
    width: 460,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        //'Create an account': function() { },
        Close: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            //$('input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
});
```

Any ideas why it happens ?

thanks

Comment: why you use `close: function() {}` ?

Comment: Can you provide more details?  This works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/62tZY/.

Comment: On display the overlay becomes slightly larger than the screen and scrollbars are added to the page which disapear on closing the dialog.

Comment: @TJVanToll the dialog has a form with few input controls and  buttons. I am not defining buttons inside the dialog definition because i want to place the buttons at places defined by me.

Comment: @Deb We're going to need a live example on jsFiddle / jsBin / codepen to help.  The code you posted works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late posting.

My page was too big containing many `divs`, `tables` and `iframes`. That is why i could not provide a `jsfiddle` as the code works fine on simpler forms.

Some of the contents in my page are left aligned while others were right aligned. I knew one of those was causing the problem for the `jquery-ui` to incorrectly determine the dimensions of the dialog.

I tried selectively removing parent `divs` and `table` elements one by one and found that one particular div which has `float:right` was the culprit.

The container `div` which was inside a `iframe` was set to `float:right`. this was causing the scrollbars to appear. I moved `float:right` from the `div` to its immediate parent and the problem is solved.

thought it might help others.

Edit : Also watchout for `Align` property that are set to `Right`